# How do I stop a program sent to run in background through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, nohup

I started a program in the background on a remote machine through `ssh` using `nohup ./program &` 
I want to kill/stop this program on remote machine as it seems like an infinite loop.
How can I do that?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

**The brute solution** [If you are not logged in after running the command ]:
`ssh` to that machine and then find the *process id (pid)* of the process that you want to kill by running the `ps ax | grep <any regex part of the command that you ran>` [e.g. `ps ax | grep java`]. After that a simple `kill <pid>` should do the trick.

**The easier solution** [If you are still in the console of that machine after running the command]: do a simple `fg`, that'd bring the process to the foreground and later you can do a `ctrl + c`. Or you can follow the similar process of finding the pid and killing the same.

Reply in case you need more assistance.

Comment: Thanks. I ran `ps ax | grep prog` and it gave me: `40697 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto prog` And when I type `ps ax | grep progr` it gives me: `40699 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto progr` What is the proces sif? 40697 or 40699?

Comment: @user140704: buddy neither of this will help you. Can you tell the command which you ran, the one you want to kill now? I need the full the command please.

Comment: In `ps ax (or l,-f,etc) |grep xyz` the `ps` list includes the `ps` and `grep` processes themselves and the `grep` matches and shows itself, in addition to the desired process(es). If looking for program name only not commandline argument(s), using `ps` default format (no `x` etc) avoids this. Otherwise, common workarounds are `|grep program |grep -v grep` or `|awk '/program/&&!/awk/'` or a pattern tweak like `|grep '[p]rogram'`. Or better just use `pgrep` (with `-l` if you want to manually verify) which excludes itself, plus defaults to all processes.

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually the process was killed due to memory error. Thats why not showing up.

Comment: Cool in that case!!